# How to add new controller in angular.module like MyController

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In same you can append an component to you module

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view2.html',
    controller: 'View2Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [$scope, function($scope) {

}])
.controller('View2Ctrl', [$scope, function($scope) {

}]);
```

Other way would be you can just store your module in some variable and do use that variable while appending angular component to `angular.module`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  //..code here
}])

app.controller('View1Ctrl', [$scope, function($scope) {

}])
app.controller('View2Ctrl', [$scope, function($scope) {

}]);
```

More preferred way would be to use IIFE pattern In that case there you wont store any global variable, As IIFE create a closer function that scope ends when function gets end

**App.js**

```
function(){
    angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      //..code here..
    }])
}();
```

**View1Ctrl.js**

```
function(){
    angular.module('myApp.view1')
    .controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {

    }]);
}();
```

**View2Ctrl.js**

```
function(){
    angular.module('myApp.view1')
    .controller('View2Ctrl', [function() {

    }]);
}();
```

Comment: you should add the second view to your $routeProvider

Comment: @svarog he just wanted to know how controllers gets added in module..do you think that important

Comment: I don't know his use case, so for completion sake it may be useful

Answer (score 0):

I've added another controller declaration, and added it to $routeProvider, see the [relevant developer guide page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) for more info

```
angular.module('view1', 'view2', ['ngRoute'])  
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  })
   .when('/view2', {
    templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
    controller: 'myController'
  })
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {

}]);

.controller('myController', [function() {

}]);
```

note that appending multiple controllers into a single file is not a recommended practice

Comment: should support your claim about more than one controller in a file is not recommended. There is no negative impact other than opinionated project structure